# How can one unstuck an unconfirmed transaction with Bither?

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, bither

I've sent a [transaction](https://blockchain.info/de/tx/ee2c05fe58e375f6ec71e4becb6219c673c934569eb2e88fc498f5a42a78ca52) with the `Bither` wallet, but accidentally included too little fee. I've since updated my wallet software, so it shouldn't happen again. However, what can I do to speed up the stuck transaction's confirmation or to replace it?

---

<sup>*This is a complementary question to [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406) which answers the question's broader implications and proposes mitigation mostly focused on Bitcoin Core.*</sup>

Comment: Your fee is about a factor of ten too low. Your wallet software may be outdated, in that case please update to a newer version.

Comment: Happy to increase the fee. Also updated my software using Bither and increased the fee for my next transactions. However, how do I increase the fee on this specific transaction. Sorry, probably a basic question, but I don't know. Many thanks for help!

Comment: I've updated the question to ask the underlying question.